# Deep dive into angular packages using npm link

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I want to get a deeply understanding with angular

So, I pulled the repository of angular in local

And i thought that how to apply this angular in local with `debug console` to my current project?

I searched, got an answer of using `npm link`!

So i moved the directory of angular repository, `~/Angular/angular/packages/common` which i want to understand espacially in angular

I typed `npm link` in `~/Angular/angular/packages/common`, it saids, `success Registered "@angular/common".`

So i moved to my project currently working on, `~/MyAngularProject`

`MyAngularProject` includes `package.json` which is also includes `angular`, `node_modules`, `ts_config.json`, `src` etc.

I removed the directory of `~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/@angular/common` so that i can `symlink` properly the `@angular/common` which i just linked before at `~/Angular/angular/packages/common`.

And i typed `npm link '@angular/common'`

the directory created also in `~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/@angular/common` which i just removed

I typed like `ng serve` in `~/MyAngularProject`

it saids

```
DLL: Checking if DLLs are valid.
{ Error: Cannot find module '@angular/common'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
    at DllBundlesControl.getPackageJsonPath (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/src/DllBundlesControl.ts:237:39)
    at DllBundlesControl.getPackageJson (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/src/DllBundlesControl.ts:224:32)
    at ~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/src/DllBundlesControl.ts:122:21
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at DllBundlesControl.getMetadata (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/src/DllBundlesControl.ts:121:8)
    at DllBundlesControl.analyzeState (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/src/DllBundlesControl.ts:144:17)
    at DllBundlesControl.checkBundles (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/src/DllBundlesControl.ts:50:17)
    at DllBundlesPlugin.run (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/src/DllBundlesPlugin.ts:38:24)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/src/DllBundlesPlugin.ts:32:59)
    at next (/MyAngularProject/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:140:14)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/src/watch-mode.ts:12:13)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:142:13)
    at Watching._go (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:43:16)
    at Watching.<anonymous> (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:34:8)
    at Compiler.readRecords (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:372:10)
    at new Watching (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:31:16)
    at Compiler.watch (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:203:17)
    at Object.startWatch (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/Shared.js:159:29)
    at Shared (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/Shared.js:221:8)
    at module.exports (~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/middleware.js:22:15) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
Error: DllBundlesPlugin: Some packages have errors.
    at ~/MyAngularProject/node_modules/src/DllBundlesControl.ts:65:19
    at <anonymous>
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:696:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Anybody could help me out please?

Comment: Did you build angular? The generated packages are inside the dist-packages folder..

Comment: Do you mean that `the generated packages` are `common` package which i linked `common` package using `npm link`?
Should i build whole packages of angular, But only `common` package? @MikeOne

Comment: If my assumption is right, how to build package of `@angular/common`? is there a reference or guide of this with a correctly way??

Comment: You should build the complete angular package. Look on github for the contribution guidelines. There are instructions on how to build Angular from a fork.

Comment: And don’t mix it with your own app. The simplest way is to make a file link inside your apps package.json and point to the package-dist versions.